# Two Things Printing at the same time

Tags: python

I'm working on developing a basic programming language and I'm trying to add a way to print errors and put arrows under the part of the line with the error. But, the things are printing at the same time... for example, if you had two strings `a = '123'` and `b = 'abc'` and my code would look something like this

```
a = '123'
b = 'abc'
print(a)
print(b)
```

The resulting code would print
`'1a2b3c'`

*How can I get the second print to wait on the first one to be done?*

I tried to combine the two commands together but that caused more usual problems... like characters being skipped and some things not printing at all... "

I can post the full code if it'll help, but I didn't because it's a few hundred lines long and probably very sloppy...

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code you posted cannot possibly produce `'1a2b3c'`.  Show us something that *actually reproduces the problem*.

Comment: It was an example because I have no idea what causes the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a programming language, you must know how to process high level programs in low level program, as this happens keeping the logic and CPU processing commands in sequence and two things cannot be processed together. This is logically impossible.

You can review [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language))